# nmap against windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, scanning, nmap

When executing the `**smb-enum-shares.nse**` script against a *Windows XP* host, I receive the output I'm expecting (shares, path etc.).  However, when running the same script against a *Windows 7* host, nothing happens.

Please see the output below:

> Starting Nmap 5.61TEST4 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-01-10 10:21
>
> Nmap scan report for 172.24.26.23
>
> Host is up (0.00s latency).
>
> PORT    STATE SERVICE
>
> 445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.80 seconds

What is going on?

**Notes:**

- nmap was run with correct credentials of the remote host
- I'm on windows XP

Comment: did you check windows 7 "password protected file sharing"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UAC turned on? Do you use account with administrative permissions?

http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-shares.html

Comment: UAC is turned off. I use the **smbpassword** and **smbusername** with the correct credentials (local administrator of the windows 7 host) but still it doesn't work....